# Deleting an node in Binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is not an homework. I am just totally blocked on this. I know what to do but I am having difficulty manipulating the tree.

It seems like the below code works for leaf nodes but does not work for other case. The following code compiles. Please help.

```
package com.binarytree;

import com.binarytree.Node;

public class BinaryTree1 {
    private Node root;
    private Node parent;

    public BinaryTree1(){
        root = null;
    }

    public Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public Node insert(int data){
        return insert(root, data);
    }

    private Node insert(Node node, int data){
        if( node == null ) {
            node = new Node(data);
        }
        else{
            if (data <= node.data){
                node.left = insert(node.left, data);
            }
            else{
                node.right = insert(node.right, data);
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    public void printTree(Node node){
        if( node == null) return;

        //System.out.println( "left: " + (node.left != null ? node.left.data : null) );
        printTree(node.left);
        System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        //System.out.println( "right: " + (node.right != null ? node.right.data : null) );
        printTree(node.right);
    }

    /**
     * case 0: no children - leaf node - delete the parent link 
     * case 1: 1 child - make the parent to point to the node child and delete
     * case 2: find min from right sub tree, copy value in targetted node and delete duplicate node
     *          (OR)
     *         find max from left sub tree, copy value in targetted node and delete duplicate node
     * @param root
     * @param data
     */
    public Node deleteNode(Node myroot, int data){
        if( myroot == null) return null;
        else if( data < myroot.data ){ //left sub tree
            myroot.left = deleteNode(myroot.left, data);
        }
        else if (data > myroot.data){
            myroot.right = deleteNode(myroot.right, data);
        }

        else{ //found the node
            //no child
            if( myroot.left == null  && myroot.right == null ){
                myroot = null;
                parent = myroot;
            }
            else if( myroot.left == null && myroot.right != null){
                parent.right = myroot.right;    
                myroot = null;
            }
            else if (myroot.left != null && myroot.right == null){
                parent.left = myroot.right;
                myroot = null;
            } //2 children
            else{
                Node temp = myroot.right;
                myroot.data = temp.data;
                myroot.right = myroot.right.right;
            }
        }

        parent = myroot;

        return parent;
    }

}


package com.binarytree;

public class RunBinaryTree1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BinaryTree1 bt = new BinaryTree1();
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(5));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(3));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(4));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(1));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(6));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(9));
//      bt.setRoot(bt.insert(2));

        System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.getRoot());
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.deleteNode(bt.getRoot(), 1));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(1));

        //DOES NOT WORK
        System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.deleteNode(bt.getRoot(), 6));
    }
}


package com.binarytree;

public class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    int data;

    public Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possibilities to watch out for when deleting a node from a balanced tree, which is usually the case for search trees. If your trees aren't meant to be self-balancing, ignore the bits that discuss it. Even if they *are* self-balancing, that particular aspect is complicated and probably worthy of a different question.

Also keep in mind the example trees below aren't *actually* balanced, they're just being used to show the actions.

---

First, if your node is a leaf. In that case, it's easy. You just delete the node. The transition then becomes, to delete D:

```
  B             B
 / \           / \
A   C    ==>  A   C
     \
      D
```

If you're using balanced trees for this case, start balancing at the parent of the node you deleted (C) and work your way up the tree from there.

---

Second case, it has *one* child. In that case, you simply "bring" that child up, pointers and all. For example, deleting C in the following:

```
  B             B
 / \           / \
A   C    ==>  A   D
     \             \
      D             E
       \
        E
```

If the tree is self-balancing, you would start at the node you shifted up in to, D in this case.

---

The third case is a little trickier in that the node you're deleting has *two* children so you can neither delete it nor bring up a child node.

What you do in that case is to swap the data in that node with the data of its immediate predecessor, which is guaranteed to be either a leaf node or a node with a left child only.

Then you simply revert back to case 1 or 2 above and delete the predecessor node (which now contains the data you want to remove) and rebalance using the appropriate rules, if desired.

Let's say you want to delete F from the following, you first swap F with its predecessor E then delete F (from a leaf node in this case, so using case 1 above):

```
  B             B               B
 / \           / \             / \
A   F    ==>  A   E    ==>    A   E
   / \           / \             / \
  D   G         D   G           D   G
 / \   \       / \   \         /     \
C   E   H     C   F   H       C       H
              (swap EF)        (del F)
```

This works for the same reason it does in a list:

```
Index: 12345678
       ABCDEFGH
```

If you want to remove F from that list but the sixth position is somehow protected, you can swap the data at indexes 5 and 6:

```
Index: 12345678
       ABCDFEGH
```

then delete the data at index 5:

```
Index: 1234567
       ABCDEGH
```

The way you *find* the immediate predecessor of a node (with two children) is to go to it's left child then keep going right until the right child is NULL, pseudo-code such as:

```
def predecessor(n):
    pre = n.left
    while pre.right != null:
        pre = pre.right
    return pre
```

Comment: This procedure works for plain binary tree, it does nothing to maintain balance. If you need to keep your tree balanced, the procedure is much more complex.

Comment: @Arkadiy, i mentioned where you had to start rebalancing in both end cases. Suggest you read again. The info in this answer covers what the question asked, adding rebalancing would triple its size unnecessarily.

Comment: All I am saying is that "when deleting a node from a balanced tree" would be better as "when deleting a node from a binary tree", leaving the balancing completely out of it.

Comment: @Arkadiy, okay, I see what you're saying. In my experience, a binary _search_ tree as specified by the OP is invariably balanced. But I'll make it clear rebalancing is only required for balanced ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works. That for all the help.

```
public class RunBinaryTreeForDeleteNode {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BinaryTreeDeleteNode bt = new BinaryTreeDeleteNode();
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(5));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(3));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(4));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(1));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(6));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(9));
//      bt.setRoot(bt.insert(2));

        //start of Testing deletion of nodes.
        System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.getRoot());
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.deleteNode(bt.getRoot(), 1));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(1));
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.deleteNode(bt.getRoot(), 6));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(6));
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.deleteNode(bt.getRoot(), 3));
        bt.setRoot(bt.insert(3));
        System.out.println("");

        //BELOW CODE CORRUPTS THE TREE
        System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.deleteNode(bt.getRoot(), 5));
        //bt.setRoot(bt.insert(5));
        System.out.println("");

//      System.out.print("Nodes in the BST (In order) are: "); bt.printTree(bt.getRoot());
        //System.out.println("");
        //end of Testing deletion of nodes.
    }
}




public class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    int data;

    public Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}





public class BinaryTreeDeleteNode {
    private Node root;

    public BinaryTreeDeleteNode(){
        root = null;
    }

    public Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public Node insert(int data){
        return insert(root, data);
    }

    private Node insert(Node node, int data){
        if( node == null ) {
            node = new Node(data);
        }
        else{
            if (data <= node.data){
                node.left = insert(node.left, data);
            }
            else{
                node.right = insert(node.right, data);
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    public void printTree(Node node){
        if( node == null) return;

        //System.out.println( "left: " + (node.left != null ? node.left.data : null) );
        printTree(node.left);
        System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        //System.out.println( "right: " + (node.right != null ? node.right.data : null) );
        printTree(node.right);
    }

    /**
     * case 0: no children - leaf Node - delete the parent link 
     * case 1: 1 child - make the parent to point to the Node child and delete
     * case 2: find min from right sub tree, copy value in targetted Node and delete duplicate Node
     *          (OR)
     *         find max from left sub tree, copy value in targetted BST Node and delete duplicate Node
     * @param root
     * @param data
     */
    public Node deleteNode(Node myNode, int data) {
        if( myNode == null) return null;

        Node p, p2;

        if (data < myNode.data)
        {
            myNode.left = deleteNode(myNode.left, data);
        }
        else if( data > myNode.data)
        {
            myNode.right = deleteNode(myNode.right, data);
        }
        else
        {
            if (myNode.left == null && myNode.right == null){ //leaf node
                return null;
            }
            else if (myNode.left == null) //one child
            {
                return myNode.right;
            }
            else if (myNode.right == null) //one child
            {
                return myNode.left;
            }
            else  //2 children
            {
                p2 = myNode.right;
                p = myNode.right;

                while (p.left != null){
                    p = p.left;
                }

                p.left = myNode.left;

                return p2;
            }

        }

        return myNode;
    }

}
```